# How to hide password in firebase (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

After saving the user's data in my Firestore database, the password is not hidden (I don't need to encrypt it) just to hide it for example:

email: xx@gmail.com password:*******

[image: screenshot from database]

Comment: Why are you storing the user's password at all? You REALLY should not be doing this. Can you show the code you are using to authenticate the user?

Comment: Saving passwords in a database like this completely compromises authentication security and should be entirely avoided.

Comment: @Reema Use firebase authentication and add DB rules with authentication.

Comment: Storing a password is criminally incompetent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the password is not hidden

The password field in your document is a regular field of type String. Naming a field "password" doesn't provide any benefits at all. So there is no way you can hide that.

As also @Fogmeister mentioned in his comment, you just should **never** store the credentials in the way you did, as storing passwords in cleartext is one of the worst security risks you can inflict on your users.

If you are already using authentication, simply omit the addition of the credentials in the database.